# Rails check if HABTM association is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

I have a roles table

```
select * from roles;

 id |   name
----+----------
  1 | admin
  2 | user
  3 | author
  4 | guest
  5 | manager
```

and another table user_roles

```
select * from user_roles;

 role_id | user_id
---------+---------
       3 |       1
       3 |       2
       3 |       3
       4 |       5
       3 |       6
       5 |       7
       5 |       8
       1 |       9
       1 |      11



#role.rb

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: 'user_roles', class_name: user_class.to_s
end
```

I am trying to do some actions when a user's role is updated say, from `guest` to `author`

```
#user.rb

class Use < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :print_role_updated if: :user_roles_changed?
  .
  .

  private

  def user_roles_changed?
    user_roles.any? { |role| role.changed? }
  end

  def print_role_updated
    puts "User role changed from #{old_role} to #{new_role}"
  end
end
```

But it is not working as expected (`.changed?` is checking whether the value in `role` table is updated ?).

How do I run `print_role_updated` method whenever user roles get updated to a diffrent one?

## edit

I tried Doctor's answer but `role_updated?` is returning false even though the record is being updated

```
class Use < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  after_update :print_role_updated if: role_updated?
  .
  .


  private

  def role_updated?
    user_roles.any? {|a| a.changed?} 
  end

  def print_role_updated
    puts "User role changed from #{old_role} to #{new_role}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

try below code in model:

## user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :print_role_updated if: :user_roles_changed?
  .
  .

  private

  def print_role_updated
    puts "User role changed"
  end

  def user_roles_changed?
    u = User.find(self.id)
    u.role != self.role # it check existing role and role saved in db 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. the problem is that the HABTM relationship is updated in the db as soon as the new values are set

here is my workaround for your example to implement an HABTM changed method. may not work for your exact case but knowing this you'll get the idea

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...
  def user_role_ids=(ids)
    @user_roles_changed = ids != user_role_ids
    super(ids)
  end

  def user_roles_changed?
    !!@user_roles_changed
  end
end
```

Comment: While this wold be expensive to store, as the table gets large, serializing all IDs into a string would be a smaller variable to store in memory

Answer (score 1):

I think the `_changed?` does only work for attributes not classes.
And since you have a many to many association you can't check on one object.
I would try something in this direction:

```
if user_roles.any? {|a| a.changed?}
```

if a user only has a single role (sorry it is not clear from your code) then the following should work, or doesn't it ?

```
if user_roles.changed?
```

Update since you specified that a user can have many roles. There should be a few corrections you should consider:

```
class Use < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  after_update :print_role_updated if: user_roles.any? {|a| a.changed?} 
  .
  .


  private

  def print_role_updated
    puts "User role changed from #{old_role} to #{new_role}"
  end
end
```

Update 2:
As it turns out, `changed?` is false on newly created objects, so my previous update is not working.

Try to change the `changed?` to the following:

```
user_roles.any? { |a| a.new_record? || a.marked_for_destruction? || a.changed? }
```

To be honest it is a bit a guessing I do here, but can you please try it? I would love to see if that works

Comment: Tony thanks for your update. But the interessting part would be to know if a User has a single role or can have multiple roles.

Comment: A user can have multiple roles

Comment: user_role table has no belongs_to user

Comment: I've updated my answer, have you tried my if. If so what is the behaviour you see?

Comment: I tried your answer(see the edit) but `role_updated?` is returning false. Nut record is updated successfully

Comment: Updated again. Please have a look at it

Comment: unfortunately update2 does not work either! I have no idea why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148391/discussion-between-doktor-oswaldo-and-tony-vincent).